How to use HTTP_INTERCEPTORS along with provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
I'm trying to implement Microsoft Msal in Angular 18, I got errors when I'm adding
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true,
},

along with
provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi(), withFetch()),

these are the errors I get.
How should i provide MsalInterceptor?

